# How do I get @PersistenceContext to load my EntityManager in CDI?

Tags: java, jpa, java-ee-6, cdi

I'm currently looking at building a new application without using Spring, rather I'm trying to do all of my injection using CDI.

I have a DAO that looks like the following:

```
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class TestDao
{
    @PersistenceUnit(unitName="DefaultPersistenceUnit")
    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="DefaultPersistenceUnit")
    private EntityManager em;

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY)
    public void test ( )
    {
        System.err.println ("EMF == " + emf);
        System.err.println ("EM == " + em);
    }
}
```

When I run the test method, I see the following:

```
EMF == org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ReloadableEntityManagerFactory@1e3b8c4
EM == null
```

So its fairly obvious that my EntityManager is not getting loaded by CDI. It seems like it should, but no joy.

I've tried hosting on both TomEE and WebSphere Liberty profile, but the effect is the same in both cases.

Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm stumped...

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@PersistenceContext` and `@TransactionManagement` are used by EJB. To make it work your component must be EJB. Add `@Stateless` to your class to make it work. You will need ejb project or nest bean in war.

Comment: That didn't make any difference. I added the @Stateless annotation to the TestDao class, but I still do not get an EntityManager injected to the instance when I get to the test method.

Comment: How you are accessing TestDao? When you add @ Stateless you should inject it using @ EJB. And make sure that you have transaction-type="JTA" in the persistent.xml

Comment: Turns out that my problem was the transaction-type. I was trying to be as simple as possible in my initial attempts, so I was using RESOURCE_LOCAL transaction type in my persistence.xml. It seems that CDI won't inject a RESOURCE_LOCAL entity manager, only one that is marked as JTA, as @Gas mentioned in his comment above...

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm not sure why are you trying to inject both of them, it should throw errors, because, from my experience, persistence is injected either by `@PersistenceContext` for `EntityManager` or `@PersistenceUnit` for `EntityManagerFactory`, not both. Also, you can get `EntityManager` from `EntityManagerFactory` with `createEntityManager()` method, so I don't understand the problem.